# Is something like this possible in Python?

Tags: python, windows, redirect, io, system

I have an executable file (hello.exe) that was given to me by a friend. This executable file creates another exe file (test.exe) and runs the executable through another command line window. I wanted to was attempting to write a script that ran hello.exe, and grabbed the output of test.exe. I'm very new to python and am familiar with system calls and redirecting output, but this is a special case because I am not directly accessing test.exe. Another problem I am facing is that hello.exe waits for a keyboard response from test.exe before doing anything else. Is it possible for me to run my hello.exe script and grab the output from test.exe in the same script?

```
import sys, string, os

os.system(hello.exe) > "test.txt" //Something like this?? Grab output from test.exe and put in test.txt
print "test" //this doesn't print until keystroke from terminal running test.exe
```

Comment: in general questions starting with "is it possible" always are answered with "yes, its possible" , however it may not be feasable

Comment: Have a look at the `subprocess.Popen` class, and the `communicate` method.

Comment: @JoranBeasley What would be a better way to phrase it?

Answer (score 2):

perhaps

```
os.system("hello.exe > test.txt")
```

alternatively

```
subprocess.Popen("hello.exe",stdout=open("test.txt","w")).communicate("\n")
```